# How does .getTime() work?

Tags: javascript, loops, frame-rate

why does this statement work? I am attempting to update my screen at 20-25 frames per second. I understand why this works I just do not understand how it works. If we take new Date().getTime() - lastLoopRun, why is the outcome not zero every time since lastLoopRun is equal to new Date().getTime()? I know it has something to do with the fact that the variable starts at 0 but thats not making much sense to me.

```
var lastLoopRun = 0;
function loop() {
        if (new Date().getTime() - lastLoopRun > 40) {
            handleControls(); 
            showSPrites();

            lastLoopRun = new Date().getTime();
        }
        setTimeout('loop();', 2);
    }
```

Comment: because the time changes and it is only updated when it goes into the if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `lastLoopRun` is checked, it hasn't been updated to the current time yet.

So at the beginning of the loop, it still either has its old value from the previous loop, or 0.

If it were updated at the beginning of the loop, it would always be 0 like you said.

Comment: hmmm ok so this would mean that new Date().getTime() is beginning at the start of the loop and its being influenced by the setTImeout method. Correct?

Comment: Ignore setTimeout for now, it just calls the loop again in 2 seconds. `getTime()` always returns the current time, but at the start of the loop, `lastLoopRun` isn't set to the current time. It's set to the time when the previous loop ended. That's why subtracting it from the current time doesn't give you 0.

Comment: Alright sorry for bothering again but I just want to make sure I am getting this straight. So in the if statement, new Date().getTime() is being subtracted by 0 because var lastLoopRun = 0. This will always make that if statement greater than 40.  Then the lastLoopRun is being updated to the current time, and creates a time difference.

Comment: Yeah, the if statement is always true in the first loop, and then after that it's only true if more than 40ms passed since the last time it was true.

Answer (score 0):

`new Date().getTime()` returns the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the current time. So it is increased by 1000 for every 1 second.

`function loop() { ...; setTimeout('loop();', 2);}` calls `loop()` for every 2 milliseconds.

```
   loop() -> elapsed about 40 ms after previous action? -> after 2 ms 
-> loop() -> elapsed about 40 ms after previous action? -> after 2 ms 
-> loop() -> elapsed about 40 ms after previous action? -> after 2 ms 
-> loop() -> OK! elapsed -> do action -> update timestamp -> after 2 ms
-> loop() -> elapsed about 40 ms after previous action? -> after 2 ms 
-> ...
```